# pandas vectorized reshape to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I reshape a pandas dataframe into a numpy array, i.e. make one list item for each discrete value of foo for all the bars belonging to that entry but without manually iterating (vectorized)?

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'bar':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
display(d)
```

of the following structure

```
result = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
result
```

[image]

Comment: This should work as well. `list(df.groupby('foo')['bar'].agg(list).to_numpy())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DataFrame.groupby`, then convert to whatever structure you want

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'bar': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})

print(df.groupby('foo')['bar'].apply(list).to_list())
# python nested lists : [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]

print(df.groupby('foo')['bar'].apply(np.array).to_numpy())
# numpy ndarray:  [array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64) array([4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int64)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# all have the same size
number_of_items_per_group = d.groupby(['foo']).bar.size().max()
d.bar.values.reshape(d.foo.nunique(),number_of_items_per_group)
```